# Missing textures in imported .fbx

Tags: texturing

I grabbed a model from models resource [model i grabbed from models resource](https://www.models-resource.com/wii/nightsjourneyofdreams/model/5939/) but when I put the .fbx into blender, the model just shows up white. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are in textured view. In textured view, you are supposed to see the model with the texture applied on it but it looks like the textures are not saved in the file by it's maker. You should [change your viewport to solid view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html) to view the model. You can find this option [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=blender%20viewport%20shading&num=40&client=ms-android-sonymobile-nrev&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0y8KUxfPdAhXIbX0KHX_nBhUQ_AUIESgB&biw=360&bih=512#imgrc=yRZO5vnDRm45XM).

Comment: i tried to change views but now my model looks grey

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, [textures are not saved in the .fbx files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) so you could not see them in blender. And as you said that you can see the model grey, that's how it's supposed to look in blender without any materials or textures to it but as compared to your previous white look of your model, you can see the details I suppose....